# Workflow to build a SvelteKit SSG site into a different branch fails

Tags: git, github, github-actions, sveltekit, sveltekit-adapter-static

I'm trying to get a GitHub Actions workflow to work with my SvelteKit site but keep running into an error. I am building a website using SvelteKit and SSG and I want to put my built site into a `production` branch in the same repo as the source code.

Here is my workflow:

```
name: Build and Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "sveltekit" ]
  workflow_dispatch:
  
permissions:
  contents: write
  
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: sveltekit

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: 18.17.0

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Build
        run: npm run build

      - name: Deploy to production branch
        run: |
          git worktree add prod-branch production
          cp -r build/* /prod-branch/
          cd prod-branch
          git add .
          git commit -m "Deploying build artifacts to production"
          git push origin production
```

This successfully builds the project, and even creates the `/prod-branch/` folder, but when it tries to check out the `production` branch into the `/prod-branch/` folder, it errors out with

```
fatal: invalid reference: production
Error: Process completed with exit code 128.
```

This occurs on the "Deploy to production branch" step.  The branch has already been created (local and remote) so I'm not sure why this would happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this to work using the following workflow:

```
name: Build and Deploy

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the "main" branch
  push:
    paths-ignore:
    - '.github/**'
    branches: [ "sveltekit" ]
  
  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:
  
permissions:
  contents: write
  
# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: sveltekit
          
      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: 18.17.0

      # Install Dependencies
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install

      # Build
      - name: Build
        run: npm run build
          
      # Deploy to Production branch
      - name: Deploy to production branch
        uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          publish_dir: ./build
          publish_branch: production
```